# sailsjs update not firing

Tags: orm, model, sails.js

I have this code that should work. I have almost identical code elsewhere that works. However, the user.save doesn't fire, nor does the User.update. I realize there is a lot of extraneous code in here, I've moved a lot of stuff around trying to figure out why neither the save nor the update is working (and yes, I know I only need one, I've tried both individually already, just did it this way to illustrate).

```
User.findOneByEmail(req.param('email'), function foundUser (err, user) {
                if (err) return next(err);
E.l(user);
                if (!user) {
                    var noAccountError = [{name: 'noAccount', message: 'The email ' + req.param('email') + ' was not found.'}]
                    req.session.flash = {
                        err: noAccountError
                    }
                    res.redirect('/user/forgot');
                    return;
                }

                var userObj = {
                    lostpasswordtoken: Helper.Guid()
                }
                user["lostpasswordtoken"] = userObj.lostpasswordtoken;

                user.save(function(err){
                    if (err) {
                        E.l(err);
                    } else {
                        E.l("save workd");
                    }
                });

                User.update(user.id, userObj, function userTokenUpdated (err) {
                    E.l(user['id']);
                    E.l(JSON.stringify(userObj));
                    if (err) {
                        return res.redirect('/user/forgot');
                    }
E.l("here6");

                }); 

                MailService.SendMail({ to: user['email'], subject: 'Password Reset', 
                    body: 'Click on http://' + req.headers.host + '/user/validateforgot?e=' + user['email'] + '&t=' + userObj['lostpasswordtoken']});

                    res.view();               
                E.l("here8");
            });
E.l("here9");
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't know the notation you used, I use this generally :

```
User.update(user.id, userObj).exec(function(err, user)
{
    if(err)//error
    ....
});
```

Comment: There are two main ways to call the function... User.update(id, options, callback) and User.update(id, options).exec(callback).  I've used both throughout my code as was prudent at the time. However, I just tried this because I'm desperate and as expected, it didn't trigger the update.  Thank you!

Comment: And you have no error on console ? Maybe you have make some database modifications and need to clear it ?

Comment: jaumard, I'm wondering if that's the case. It's very odd. I have no errors, I have my config set to alter. I know I have access as I can create a new user, so I've confirmed access to the database table. I've added all those console logs and they only ones that don't fire are inside the update. I know I'm doing it right, but something somewhere is off.

Comment: omg. I'm an idiot. Was in the model. I was working on a password reset function and did a beforeUpdate in the model, but I didn't realize that the before update that I had to verify and encrypt the password was apparently preventing updates to any other fields.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, jaumard!

Comment: ^^ glad you found the solution ! :)

Comment: @iolympian your comment saved my life.